# Animating ng-include flip

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions

I'm new to css transitions and am experimenting with trying to animate the transition between two sub templates that I am including in my angularjs project using ng-include.

I am attempting to replicate the effect seen [here](http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app/#/page/1) (click on the flip option in the dropdown). However I can't seem to get the newly added template to animate its entrance correctly. The leaving template 'flips' out but the entering template just appears rather than 'flipping' in.

My page has the following basic structure:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="page flip" ng-include="something"></div>
</div>
```

I am using the following css:

```
.content {
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
    position:relative;
}
.page{
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
}
.content .page.flip {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.content .page.flip.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.content .page.flip.ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.content .page.flip.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.content .page.flip.ng-leave-active {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

I've made a plunker by adapting the ng-include demo from angular website [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1bFz9aicKEVzzjpjefYV?p=preview) to illustrate problem.

Can anyone point me to where I am going wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem you are facing. I find it is working fine except that pages are rotating vertically.

Comment: Hi @GaneshKumar, thanks for response. I've added a few lines to clarify problem, on my computer the entering template just appears rather than flipping in (except when you first load page when it seems to work). Does it work correctly on yours? Not worried about vertical

Comment: Entering is fine in your plunkr

Comment: Could I ask which browser you are viewing in? I've just tried it in Chrome and works fine. I was using safari